# Android: how to apply property animation to Drawable

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a View in which I am drawing multiple images as Drawables. I have an ImageHolder class wherein I have Drawable object and other location information. I am drawing each image/Drawable using drawable.draw(canvas) method. 
I want to apply Property animation to the images. Is there a way I can do that. Using the Frame Animation on Drawable wont serve my purpose.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you may know, Property animation creates an animation by modifying an object's property values over a set period of time with an Animator. This animator you must make as a form as "res/animator/your file names.xml" in your project. For more detailed, see [this Android API Guides](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html). It's very simple.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the Q?